# Open PHP without breaking JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops, for-loop, break

I'm iterating over a table's values to modify them if any changes have been made by the user.

Currently I have something similar to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    if (item[5]) {
        window.open("modify.php?id=" + id + "&delete=true");
    }
}
```

My question is how I can connect to my modify.php file without breaking the for loop. I tried with

```
window.location("modify.php?id=" + id + "&delete=true");
```

too but that's the same story.

I considered using window.open and setting the new windows dimension's to something very small so it appears hidden and closing it again after my PHP has finished executing.

This however seems ridiculously dumb hence why I'm wondering what a/the better approach would be?

Comment: Rather than using `window.open`, use AJAX.

Comment: `window.open` should not break the loop in question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be using AJAX here. For conciseness, I'll show you what I mean using [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    if (item[5]) {
        $.ajax("modify.php?id=" + id + "&delete=true");
    }
}
```

This sends an asynchronous HTTP GET request to the URL provided.

AJAX can be done in vanilla JavaScript too but for reasons of convenience and compatibility I would recommend using a library.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other code, why not simply copy the instructions for later use?

```
var openItems = [], i;

for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    if (item[5]) {
        openItems.push(id); // Don't open the window just yet, just copy to array
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < openItems.length; i++) {
    window.open("modify.php?id=" + openItems[i] + "&delete=true");
}
```

And if you consider that you'd only be opening one window anyway (and you want the first item to be it), then simply do the following:

```
var openID, i;

for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    if (item[5]) {
        openID = i;
        break; // No need to continue iterations
    }
}

if (openID) {
    window.open("modify.php?id=" + openID + "&delete=true");
}
```

If you want the last item to be the one you open, simply remove the `break;` statement.